# Iterate over files in linux with different numbers in title

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I would like to iterate over several files in my directory in linux which look like this:

```
SRR057629_1.fastq.gz SRR057629_2.fastq.gz SRR057630_1.fastq.gz     
SRR057630_2.fastq.gz SRR057631_1.fastq.gz SRR057631_2.fastq.gz
SRR057632_1.fastq.gz SRR057632_2.fastq.gz SRR057633_1.fastq.gz
SRR057633_2.fastq.gz
```

The challenge for me is that I would need `SRR..._1` and `SRR..._2` as input for one command (tophat2) and thereafter take the next couple of `SRR***_1` and `SRR***_2` for the same command. In principle it would look like this:

```
tophat2 -G /Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf /Homo_sapiens /UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/genome SRR057636_1.fastq.gz SRR057636_2.fastq.gz
tophat2 -G /Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf /Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/genome SRR057637_1.fastq.gz SRR057637_2.fastq.gz
```

So how could I change these numbers (bold) for each command??

```
SRR0576**29**_1.fastq.gz

SRR0576**29**_1.fastq.gz
```

Best wishes,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in *_1.fastq.gz; do
   tophat2 -G /Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf /Homo_sapiens /UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/genome $a ${a/_1/_2}
done
```